# Communication between two REST Services

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jelastic

I have two REST Services (developed using Spring Boot), one for Authentication and one that returns Data. The Data service validates a token against the Authentication service when data i requested. The validation is done by the Data service sending a request to the Authentication service containing an ID like this `https://name.com/auth/key?id=[ID]`. I have tested the validation by having the Authentication service deployed as a WAR-file on a Tomcat server `https://name.com/auth/` and having the Data service running local on my computer. This setup worked fine. Now I have deployed the Data service as WAR-file to the same Tomcat server `https://name.com/data/`. The issue now is that the Data service is not able to connect to the Authentication service giving the following error message

```
HTTP Status 500 - I/O error on GET request for "https://name.com/auth/key": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Why is the connection refused when both WAR-files are running on the same Tomcat server?

Comment: Using spring boot and deploying to Tomcat container? why would you do that.. just use the embedded tomcat

Comment: Spring boot is designed to run independently, not deployed in an App server

Answer (score 0):

The issue was by using the internal IP addresses rather then the external.